# Regex - How to match a text which starts with square bracket but doesn't end with square bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to match a text which should be able to match a pattern in JavaScript. The pattern should be able to match if there is any text which starts with opening square bracket "[" but doesn't end with "]".

Look at the below example:

1. `This is a [Sample text` -> This should return me `[Sample text`
2. `This is [again] a [sample text` -> This should also return me `[sample text`

I have tried multiple ways like below:

```
\[([^\]]+)\.*[^}]$
```

And

```
\[([^\]]+)\.*[^}]$
```

But both of them are not working as expected. I am not very good in Regex patterns hence seeking a help here.

Thanks

Comment: I think you might need a negative look-ahead?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+regex+mismatch*+square+brackets+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: \[(?!.*\[)[\w ]+(?!\])

Comment: Will `\[[^]]*$` work for you?

Comment: @anubhava this is working as expected, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex for your job:

```bash
/\[[^\]]*$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LrsJ13/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\[`: Match a `[`
- `[^\]]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that is not a `]`
- `$`: End